# How can I use Object.assign() to create this state object how I want it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I'm using Redux to create a simple contacts application. My state object looks like the following:

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "name": "Miguel Camilo",
      "phone": "123456789"
    },
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "phone": "883292300348"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jessica",
      "phone": "8743847638473"
    },
    {
      "name": "Michael",
      "phone": "0988765553"
    }
  ],
  "activeContact": {
    "name": "Peter",
    "phone": "883292300348"
  }
}
```

I am creating an action to add a contact. I want to add a new object to the `contacts` array within the state containing the name and number that are coming from input fields on the page. I am using `Object.assign()` to try and do this but I am getting an error `bundle.js:22875 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` and I believe it is coming from my use of `Object.assign()` in the reducer. This is my reducer code:

```
export default function (state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_CONTACT':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
      contacts: state.concat([
        {
          name: action.payload.name,
          phone: action.payload.phone
        }
      ])
    })
    default:
      return state;
    }
}
```

So if `action.payload.name` is "Jeff" and `action.payload.phone` is "5647876578" I want the state returned to look like:

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "name": "Miguel Camilo",
      "phone": "123456789"
    },
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "phone": "883292300348"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jessica",
      "phone": "8743847638473"
    },
    {
      "name": "Michael",
      "phone": "0988765553"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jeff",
      "phone": "5647876578"
    }
  ],
  "activeContact": {
    "name": "Peter",
    "phone": "883292300348"
  }
}
```

I can't seem to find the issue in my use of Object.assign() but I'm pretty sure this is where my error is coming from. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: Logging state in the reducer returns the following:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Miguel Camilo",
    "phone": "123456789"
  },
  {
    "name": "Peter",
    "phone": "883292300348"
  },
  {
    "name": "Jessica",
    "phone": "8743847638473"
  },
  {
    "name": "Michael",
    "phone": "0988765553"
  }
]
```

My ContactsList component:

```
class ContactList extends Component {
  renderList() {
    return this.props.contacts.map((contact) => {
      return (
        <li
          key={contact.phone}
          onClick={() => this.props.selectContact(contact)}
          className='list-group-item'>{contact.name}</li>
      );
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className = 'list-group col-sm-4'>
        {this.renderList()}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    contacts: state.contacts
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ selectContact: selectContact }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContactList)
```

My `ActiveContact` portion of the state is getting modified like this in it's reducer:

```
export default function (state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CONTACT_SELECTED':
      return action.payload
  }
  return state;
 }
```

Comment: If you're trying to change state immutably, I think you should use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state)) to make immutable copy then add new contact and then return modified state

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting this error is that your initial state has no `contacts` array:

```
export default function (state = {}, action) {
...
}
```

Try revising your state so that it initially has an empty contacts array like so:

```
export default function (state = { contacts : [] }, action) {
...
}
```

Also, consider revising your `'ADD_CONTACT'` action to use `Array#concat` like so:

```
case 'ADD_CONTACT':
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    contacts: state.contacts.concat([
      {
        name: action.payload.name,
        phone: action.payload.phone
      }
    ])
  })
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be the case. I am still getting the same error

Comment: Since this reducer is only dealing with `contacts` should it be returning the full state object or just a new `contacts`?

Comment: No. Now I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined` so it appears `contacts` is undefined? Seems odd

Comment: I added it to my original post. It seems `state` in the reducer only contains the `contacts`. Not sure why that is but that was what led me to believe I should only be returning `contacts`

Comment: Well, I changed my ADD_CONTACT reducer and updated it on the OP. I am now getting `bundle.js:22563 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.contacts.map is not a function` and the error is occurring in my `ContactsList` component. Looking more into it now, but still not sure what that's happening... I added the ContactList code to the post as well

Comment: Looks like you made a minor copy error - the code should be `contacts: state.contacts.concat([` not `contacts: state.concat([`

Comment: I did try it the first way and it was not working. So I thought I should only be returning the `contacts` object, not wrapped in a parent state object, that was why I removed the `contacts` This was because in my reducer `state` is only the `contacts` object and not the full state object I thought it was